# getResource not working (Even though I have a correct pathfile)

Tags: image

[NOTE: This thread is edited.. cause the first question is already answered but the current question is not]

Can someone tell me why this is not working?

This is from a tutorial. I read a lot on different threads about this problem and I found out that I need to create a new Source Folder. I name it to Images then add Hello.jpg to it by dragging the image into the folder and it works.

Now they said that in order to use the image you need to put "/nameofthefolder/file.filetype/"
So I put it in the correct path.

But my problem is, it is not working.. My code is very simple.. Add an image to an JLabel

I can't put an picture on because I need 10 rep..  but I create a Source Folder and add Image to that folder correctly I promise

I know this question sounds stupid but I am very new to programming... please have a kind consideration on the beginner..

```
package myGUI102;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class myGUIAddImage extends JFrame{
    private ImageIcon image1;
    private JLabel label1;


    myGUIAddImage (){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        image1 = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/Images/Hello.jpg"));
        label1 = new JLabel (image1);
        add (label1);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myGUIAddImage mygui = new myGUIAddImage();
        mygui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mygui.setVisible(true);
        mygui.pack();
        mygui.setTitle("My Image");


    }

}
```

Comment: I try to read other threads about this but they their solution wont work for me... and other have no clear answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the below code

```
Intent mainactivity = new Intent("com.neoapps.quizj.QUIZJMENU");

startActivity(mainactivity);
```

with

```
Intent mainactivity = new Intent(this,Quizjmenu.class);

startActivity(mainactivity);
```

This will start Quizjmenu activity. Between i don't actually understand what you are trying to achieve by directly re-directing users from MainActivityQuizj to Quizjmenu when they start your app.

Doesn't the purpose of MainActivityQuizj gets defeated in this instance ? (or) maybe this is just an example code from which you are trying to put forward your issue.

Also, your android manifest for activity needs to be updated as per the below,

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivityQuizj"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".Quizjmenu"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I would like to know why "com.neoppas.quizj.QUIZJMENU" wont work?.